# Phonons to solve solid mechanics problems?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, phonons, solid-mechanics

From what I understand, phonons can be used to solve acoustics or optics problems, but can we used phonons to solve a solid mechanics problem?

The first answer I expect is :"Acoustics wave are solid mechanics problem". Yes, but can we solve a problem that not involves waves. If we take for example, an axial compression test on a simple 3D solid material. Can use the concept of phonons to handle this problem an compute the stress and/or strain?

If, the answer is yes, I would be interested to understand how to do this with the appropriate equations.

## Edit

I think that if we can recover the interatomic distance from the phonons density (or an other parameter), we should be able to compute the strain and stress.

Starting with a 1D spring chain based on Debye model, with fixed ends; we know that the density of phonons follows the Bose-Einstein distribution. But I do not see any dependency with the interatomic distance. So is it possible, to recover the interatomic distance with the phonons concept ?

From there, if we apply a compression on this 1D spring chain by reducing its length, without change of the temperature; is there any change in the phonons properties that we can track to compute the stress or strain or variation of the mean interatomic distance ?

Comment: Would you consider thermoelasticity a solid mechanics problem?

Comment: Yes. But I would like to assume that there is no coupling (in a first approach, to keep things simple at the beginning).

Comment: The case that came to mind was the finite speed of heat propagation. In the typical undergrad-level thermoelastic transient treatment, if I heat up one end of a km-long ceramic rod, the other end immediately begins to extend and expand. But this isn't possible in reality because lattice vibrations have a finite speed.

Comment: What do you mean by "using phonons" to solve a problem? Are you talking about making an analog computer where the phonons are used to perform the calculation? Conceptualizing the problems in terms of phonons? Needing to take phonons into account as part of a larger solution?

Comment: @Inmaurer I was more thinking about conceptualizing the problem (and its resolution) in terms of phonons. But your question about using phonons to perform calculations in a computer, pick up my curiosity. Is it possible ?